# unable to bring mdi child form in front

Tags: c#, mdi

I have a MDI Parent form in which I open MDI Child forms, but I don't want to reopen them if i click another time, instead of that i want to focus on that particular mdi Child form which is already opened, and i am doing this job from clicking my menu strip. i already tried a lot to do this successfully, but got failed all the time. well my code is :

this is a Method...

```
private bool CheckMdiClientDuplicates(string WndCls)
{
    Form[] mdichld = this.MdiChildren;
    if (this.MdiChildren.Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    foreach (Form selfm in mdichld)
    {
        string str = selfm.Name;
        str = str.IndexOf(WndCls).ToString();
        if (str != "-1")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and i am implementing this method via...

```
private void myToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyForm f = new MyForm();//MyForm is the form on which i am working
    if (CheckMdiClientDuplicates("MyNamespace.MyForm") == true)
    {
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        f.Activate();
        f.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`f` is still your `new MyForm()`, so what do you expect `Activate`ing it will do? You need to get the actual form you want to bring to the front and `Activate` that.

Additionally, you probably don't want to make a new `MyForm` unless you intend to use it.

Comment: @Sandy.Net Look at your code. You are creating a new form with `MyForm f = new MyForm()` and then trying to do `f.Activate()`...

Comment: so what should i do in this case sir? should i close the from first and then reopen it with a new instance?

Comment: @Sandy.Net You should call `Activate()` on the *existing* MyForm object, not create a new one. The best solution would probably be to return a `MyForm` from `CheckMdiClientDuplicates`, not a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

This is when you click a button for your first form to appear:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Form1 f1 = null;
        if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form1)) == null)
        {
            if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
            {
                ActiveMdiChild.Close();
            }
            f1 = new Form1();
            f1.MdiParent = this;
            f1.Show();
        }
}
```

Method:

```
public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
    {
        foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
                return OpenForm;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Do the same when you click the next button for the other form.